# How to realize a multi-client capability in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-theory, neo4j-apoc

### Initial situation

I have several independent and disconnected graphs, each of them have a hierarchical like structure with a local root element. Each of these graphs consists of approximately 8 million nodes and 40 million relationships. I have successfully created a three-digit number of Cypher queries, which should now be applied to a single graph only and not the entirety of all graphs. The graph, the queries have to apply to, is specified by its root node.

[image: grpah]

### Challenge to be solved

How can I realize a kind of pseudo multi-client capability for a graph, if all graphs have to remain in a common Neo4j database for reasons of reporting and pattern matching?

---

### approach to the problem / preliminary result

- Implement a single shortest path to the given root element for selection purposes in really every query at the beginning? **Cons:**

  - huge performance losses expected
  - with high development costs
- Expand each graph with a separate, additional label? **Cons:**

  - complex queries, high development effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these cases, adding a specific label per tenant/client to all nodes in the subgraph tends to be the approach taken. It would require you to ensure that when you match to the relevant nodes in the query that you additionally make sure the nodes you're working with have the client's label present.

As a note for the future, native multi-tenancy support is one of the key features we're working on for the next year.